# How to prove that $2+2 = 2*2 = 2^2 \cdots= 4$

Tags: arithmetic

One day, I noticed that

$2+2 = 2*2 = 4$.

Later, I learned that

$2+2 = 2*2 = 2^2 = 4$

Multiplication is an abstraction of *a lot of additions* , exponential is an abstraction of *a lot of multiplications*...  I'm sure there is always an abstraction of the previous operation.

But my questions is : if I use any abstraction with the numbers $2$ and $2$ does it always result $4$ ?

Comment: $2/2=1$, case closed.

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation and at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function.

Comment: @Raskolnikov $3/3 = 1$ and $3+3 ≠ 3^3$  I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. The question is asking whether $2$ tetrated to $2$ or $2$ pentated to $2$ and so forth always results in $4$ (and also a proof it seems). Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: See Corollary 2(iii) on p. 97 of: John Doner and Alfred Tarski, [*An extended arithmetic of ordinal numbers*](http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~doner/articles/Doner-Tarski.pdf), **Fundamenta Mathematica** 65 (1969), 95-127.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the "deep" reason for this is that these are all *binary* operations.

Given a binary operation $\ast$ on integers at least $2$, define $\ast'$ by $$m\ast' n = \overbrace{m\ast m\ast \cdots \ast m}^{n\text{ times}}.$$
Always associate to the right (for concreteness), so that $a\ast b\ast c = a\ast(b\ast c)$ and so on.

Now starting with any binary operation $\ast$, define $\ast_1=\ast$ and $\ast_{n+1} = \ast_n'$. Then for all $n$ we clearly have $2\ast_n 2 = 2\ast_{n-1} 2 = \cdots = 2\ast 2$.

The sequence you consider is given by taking $\ast$ to be $+$.

Comment: This is what we always do in a vector space.

Comment: Exercise: Find $\ast$ such that $\ast'$ is $+$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I think the operation $*$ such that $*'$ is $+$, is **incrementation** and needs just one number. :)

Comment: @SeanEberhard: Well, as $a\ast'1=a$, that makes the exercise tricky...

Comment: @GeorgeLowther I only defined $\ast'$ on integers at least $2$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: Ah, I missed that bit. In that case, the exercise does have a solution.