# $2 \uparrow^n 2 = 4$ and the magnificence of $2$

Tags: logic, proof-writing, exponentiation, tetration

I was reading up on tetration when I realized:
$$2 \uparrow\uparrow 2 = 2\uparrow 2 = 2 \times 2 = 2+2 =4$$
Infact, when generally speaking:
$$ 2 \uparrow^n 2 =4$$
Now, I realize that this is because of [the binary nature of binary operations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483959/how-to-prove-that-22-22-22-cdots-4).
I  require a formal way to prove that $2 \uparrow^n 2 = 4$
Please, can you help?

Comment: @user2345215: Oh I realized it just now! Dang, I was thinking in terms of tetration!

Comment: @EricStucky: Sorry, I removed that part from my question. Just a logical error on my part.

Comment: sounds good, thanks :)

Comment: I removed the `\huge` because it was taking up too much space on the front page.

Comment: You were told to use induction. Where were you having trouble accomplishing that? Do you know what induction is?

Comment: @seaturtles: I see induction more as something that verifies something I have. I just hoped there was another way, ya know.

Comment: @Nick: You're asking for a proof, which is exactly "something that verifies" the thing you want to prove. If you want something done that induction doesn't do, then _proof_ certainly isn't what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well from the definition $a\uparrow^n2=a\uparrow^{n-1}a$ so for $a=2$ you get $2\uparrow^n2=2\uparrow^{n-1}2=\ldots=2\uparrow2=4$.

Comment: It's silly how beautiful such a simple idea is to me. Indeed, it's very magnificent.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use induction.

If you have the luxury of defining your operation, you should define it recursively. If not, and your definition isn't recursive, then wow that's cool but you should probably tell us about it.